# How to re-draw a jTree, from a Thread object?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtree

I am using a `jTree` structure to display the structure of the project the user is currently using. Users can, of course, open another project, and then, the software is supposed to display the new project's structure. I am using `DefaultTreeModel` to add/delete nodes, and updating the `jTree` structure. And since this task can take seconds to be achieved, it was implemented in a new `Thread`. Here's the code :

```java
class DrawTreeThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("drawing the tree");
        model = (DefaultTreeModel) jTree1.getModel();
        Fichier obs,
                open,
                opens = new Fichier(Batiment.data.getAbsolutePath() + "\\Open"), 
                obss = new Fichier(Batiment.data.getAbsolutePath() + "\\Obs"), 
                rooms = new Fichier(Batiment.data.getAbsolutePath() + "\\Rooms");
        Fichier bd = new Fichier(Batiment.data.getAbsolutePath() + "\\BuildingData" + Fichier.EXT);

        int size = rooms.listFiles().length;
        int nbrEtage = bd.readInt("etage");

        DefaultMutableTreeNode[] roomz = new DefaultMutableTreeNode[size];
        DefaultMutableTreeNode bat = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(Batiment.data.getAbsoluteName());
        DefaultMutableTreeNode[] obstacles = new DefaultMutableTreeNode[size];
        DefaultMutableTreeNode[] ouvertures = new DefaultMutableTreeNode[size];
        DefaultMutableTreeNode[] etages = new DefaultMutableTreeNode[nbrEtage];
        jTree1 = new JTree(bat);

        for (int etageCounter = 0; etageCounter < nbrEtage; etageCounter++) {
            String name = "RDC";
            if (etageCounter != 0) {
                name += " + " + etageCounter;
            }
            etages[etageCounter] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name);
            bat.add(etages[etageCounter]);
            model.insertNodeInto(etages[etageCounter], bat, 0);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            roomz[i] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rooms.listFiles()[i].getAbsoluteName());
            obs = new Fichier(obss.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + rooms.listFiles()[i].getAbsoluteName());
            open = new Fichier(opens.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + rooms.listFiles()[i].getAbsoluteName());
            etages[rooms.listFiles()[i].readInt("etage")].add(roomz[i]);
            obstacles[i] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Obstacles (" + obs.listFiles().length + ")");
            ouvertures[i] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Ouvertures (" + open.listFiles().length + ")");
            roomz[i].add(obstacles[i]);
            roomz[i].add(ouvertures[i]);

            DefaultMutableTreeNode[] Obs = new DefaultMutableTreeNode[obs.listFiles().length];
            for (int j = 0; j < obs.listFiles().length; j++) {
                Obs[j] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(obs.listFiles()[j].getAbsoluteName());
                obstacles[i].add(Obs[j]);
            }

            DefaultMutableTreeNode[] Open = new DefaultMutableTreeNode[open.listFiles().length];
            for (int j = 0; j < open.listFiles().length; j++) {
                Open[j] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(open.listFiles()[j].getAbsoluteName());
                ouvertures[i].add(Open[j]);
            }
        }

        model.nodeStructureChanged(bat);
        model.reload();

        jTree1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
        jTree1.expandRow(0);
        System.out.println("drawing the tree with success");

    }
}
```

the `new DrawTreeThread().start()` is called from a button `ActionListner()`, but nothing is happening. What's so wrong?

Comment: It maybe will help to mention that the two `System.out.println()` lines at the beginning and the end of `run()` are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jTree1 = new JTree(bat);
```

This does nothing. All you have done is create a new JTree object in memory. You haven't actually added the tree to the GUI.

There is no need to create a new tree. Instead you create a new TreeModel and update the existing tree by using:

```
tree.setModel(...);
```

Also, when you invoke the above method you should wrap it in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to the GUI is updated on the EDT.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just used `tree.setModel(...);` and it worked as it is supposed to do :)